# How to add an word for a line where transpose has done

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep

I have a file fruits:

```
apple
grapes
banana
orange
```

By using

```
cat < fruits | tr "\n" ","
```

It will give output as

```
apple,grapes,banana,orange,
```

Here I want to print the file name also along with the output
like

```
fruits|apple,grapes,banana,orange
```

How can I do it?

If it is a variable like

> $HEALTHYFRUITS

where we read all the fruits one by one and the file name is fruits

and

> echo $HEALTHYFRUITS | tr "\n" ","

here I want to print

> fruits|apple,grapes,banana,orange

Answer (score 3):

```
echo -n "$filename|"; tr "\n" "," <"$filename"
```